# Sanitation needed for WP_Query or get_posts calls?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, sanitization

Just wanted to get a straight answer on this: when submitting query_vars to a call to get_posts or WP_Query, is sanitation needed or does WordPress already take care of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Parameters given to the `WP_Query` object only need to be escaped for the database query - this is handled by WordPress.